# Does the number of permutations in $S_n$ with major index equal to $k$, satisfy a degree $k$ polynomial?

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, permutations, generating-functions, oeis

I'm interested in fixing $k$ and finding a formula, $M_k(n)$, for the number of permutations $\pi \in S_n$ such that $\operatorname{maj}(\pi) = k$, where $\mathrm{maj} \colon S_n \rightarrow \mathbb N_{\geq0}$ denotes the [major index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_index) of the permutation. (It does not change the question if you replace the major index with the inversion number or any other Mahonian statistic.)

## Table

Here's the table of values, given by OEIS sequence [A008302](https://oeis.org/A008302), where $T(n,k) = M_k(n)$:

```
n\k| 0    1    2     3     4      5      6      7       8
---+------------------------------------------------------
 1 | 1
 2 | 1,   1
 3 | 1,   2,   2,    1
 4 | 1,   3,   5,    6,    5,     3,     1
 5 | 1,   4,   9,   15,   20,    22,    20,    15,      9, ...
 6 | 1,   5,  14,   29,   49,    71,    90,   101,    101, ...
 7 | 1,   6,  20,   49,   98,   169,   259,   359,    455, ...
 8 | 1,   7,  27,   76,  174,   343,   602,   961,   1415, ...
 9 | 1,   8,  35,  111,  285,   628,  1230,  2191,   3606, ...
10 | 1,   9,  44,  155,  440,  1068,  2298,  4489,   8095, ...
11 | 1,  10,  54,  209,  649,  1717,  4015,  8504,  16599, ...
```

The table satisfies the following recurrence $$\begin{align}
T(1, 0) &= 1, \\
T(n, k) &= 0 \text { for } n < 0, k < 0 \text{ or } k > \frac{n(n-1)}{2}, \\
T(n, k) &= \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} T(n-1, k-j), \text{ or alternatively}, \\
T(n, k) &= T(n, k-1) + T(n-1, k) - T(n-1, k-n).
\end{align}$$

## Conjecture

It appears that for $n \geq k$, the $k$-th column satisfies:

0. $M_0(n) = 1$.
1. $M_1(n) = -1 + n$.
2. $\displaystyle M_2(n) = \frac{-2 - n + n^2}{2!}$.
3. $\displaystyle M_3(n) = \frac{-7 n + n^3}{3!}$.
4. $\displaystyle M_4(n) = \frac{-14 n - 13 n^2 + 2 n^3 + n^4}{4!}$.
5. $\displaystyle M_5(n) = \frac{120 - 46 n - 65 n^2 - 15 n^3 + 5 n^4 + n^5}{5!}$.
6. $\displaystyle M_6(n) = \frac{516 n - 356 n^2 - 165 n^3 - 5 n^4 + 9 n^5 + n^6}{6!}$.

I'm curious to know more about these in approximately the following order:

- Is it true that the $k$-th column, $M_k(n)$, always satisfies a degree $k$ polynomial for $n \geq k$?
- Is the constant part of $M_k(n)$ nonzero if and only if $n$ is a [generalized pentagonal number](https://oeis.org/A001318)?
- If so, is the coefficient of $x^k$ is always $\displaystyle \frac{1}{k!}$?
- Is the coefficient of $x^{k-1}$ always $\displaystyle \frac{-3n + n^2}{2k!}$?
- Is the coefficient of $x^{k-2}$ always $\displaystyle \frac{-2n + 21n^2 - 22n^3 + 3n^4}{24k!}$?
- Is the coefficient of $x^{k-m}$ always a polynomial of degree $2m$?
- Is the coefficient of $x^{k-m}$ given by a polynomial whose numerator is divisible by $\displaystyle \prod_{i=0}^{m-1} (x-i)$?
- Do these polynomials $M_k(n)$ have a combinatorial explanation in terms of (finite) exponential generating functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generating function for the inversion numbers is well known:
$$
T_{n,k}=[q^k]\frac{(1-q)(1-q^2)\cdots(1-q^{n})}{(1-q)^n}
$$
We can safely remove the factors of $(1-q^{k+1})(1-q^{k+2})\cdots(1-q^n)$ from the numerator without changing the $q^k$ coefficient, so
$$
T_{n,k}=[q^k](1-q)(1-q^2)\cdots(1-q^k)(1-q)^{-n}
$$
By the pentagonal number theorem,
$$(1-q)(1-q^2)(1-q^3)\cdots=\sum_{j\in \mathbb Z}(-1)^jq^{j(3j-1)/2}.\tag{*}$$
For this purpose, we only need the power of $q$ up to $q^k$ in $(1-q)(1-q^2)\cdots(1-q^k)$, which indeed agree with the terms of $q^k$ up to $k$ in $(*)$. Finally, $[q^i](1-q)^{-n}= \binom{n+i-1}{i}$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
T_{n,k}
&=[q^k]\left(\sum_{j\in \mathbb Z}(-1)^jq^{j(3j-1)/2}\right)\left(\sum_i q^i\binom{n+i-1}{i}\right)
\\&=\sum_{j\in \mathbb Z} (-1)^j\binom{n+k-j(3j-1)/2-1}{k-j(3j-1)/2}
\end{align}
$$
Even though this is an infinite sum, there are only finitely many $j$ for which the lower index $k-j(3j-1)/2$ is nonnegative, and only those contribute positively. This explains your observation about the pentagonal numbers.

Each binomial coefficient can be expanded into a polynomial in $n$, but I do not know how to find the coefficients of that nicely. I think the above expansion is quite pretty, since this shows that $T_{n,k}$ is a linear combination of $O(\sqrt{k})$ binomial coefficients, instead of $O(k)$ powers of $n$.